# Select combo box dynamically in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I want to append value from data base on option tag combo box. But when I first doing option tag's value empty and then I appending through `AJAX` then it only showing one value. But I want like all option should be visible but one should selected automatically.

**my code**

```
$('#b').on("click", "a", function () {
    var patid= $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"https://localhost/patient_details1.php?patid="+patid,
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(response)
    {
      ("#pat_type").html("");
       for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++) 
          {
            $('<option value="'+ response[i].pattype +'">'+ 
    response[i].pattype +'</option>').appendTo("#pat_type");
                    }
          }
    }
    });             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use $('#pat_type').empty().
2. check when you get data from your request. You need to get it
   only after loading your page.

Answer (score 0):

You having typo error `("#pat_type").html("");`

make it `$("#pat_type").html("");` or `$('#pat_type').empty();`

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
       listItems+= "<option value='" + response[i].pattype + "'>" + response[i].pattype + "</option>";
    }

    $("#pat_type").append(listItems);

// for setting selected item based on value
$('#pat_type').val('selectedvalue');
```